# How to make bidirectional adapter for two classes that implement the same interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, adapter

```
interface Server
{
    void accept(String xml);
    void send();
}

class ServerThatUsesXML implements Server
{
    Server server;

    @Override
    public void accept(String xml) {
        if (xml.equals("XML"))
            System.out.println("Data accepted successfully.");
        else
            System.out.println("There was a problem in processing the data.");
    }

    @Override
    public void send() {
        server.accept("XML");
    }
}

class ServerThatUsesJSON implements Server
{
    Server server;

    @Override
    public void accept(String json) {
        if (json.equals("JSON"))
            System.out.println("Data accepted successfully.");
        else
            System.out.println("There was a problem in processing the data.");
    }

    @Override
    public void send() {
        server.accept("JSON");
    }
}

class Converter
{
    public String convertToXML(String json)
    {
        return "XML";
    }

    public String convertToJSON(String xml)
    {
        return "JSON";
    }
}

class Adapter implements Server
{
    Server xml, json;
    Converter converter = new Converter();

    public Adapter(Server xml, Server json) {
        this.xml = xml;
        this.json = json;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(String input) {
        // converter.convertTo...
    }

    @Override
    public void send() {
        // converter.convertTo...
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerThatUsesXML xml = new ServerThatUsesXML();
        ServerThatUsesJSON json = new ServerThatUsesJSON();

        xml.server = json;
        json.server = xml;

        xml.send(); // There was a problem in processing the data.
        json.send(); // There was a problem in processing the data.

        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(xml, json);
        xml.server = adapter;
        json.server = adapter;

        xml.send();
        json.send();
        // Both calls should print "Data accepted successfully.".
    }
}
```

In this example, I have two servers. Unfortunately, one server uses `XML`, and the other uses `JSON`. They both have to communicate with each other. So I made an adapter that implements  the `Server` interface and contains the two servers. I want whenever the `ServerThatUsesXML` sends something to the adapter, the adapter converts it to `JSON` and forward it to the `ServerThatUsesJSON`. And the same holds for converting `JSON` requests to `XML` requests.

The problem is that since the two servers implement the same interface, both servers has the same methods with the same signature. So when I call `accept` for example on the `Adapter`, the `Adapter` won't know where did the request come from and which way the request should go. Should I pass it to the `JSON` server? or should I pass it to the `XML` server?

I have two solutions but they don't look so clean... So I'm asking whether there is a better approach to solve this problem.

First solution: to check the format of the text. If it's an `XML` text, convert it to `JSON` and send it to the `ServerThatUsesJSON`. The same holds for the requests converting from `JSON` to `XML`. This approach is probably the worst, since it doesn't check the sender and forwards the requests only based on the format of the text. Also it goes through the text to check the format. This is not so efficient.

Second solution: to make two adapters, one that accepts `XML` and sends `JSON`, and another one that accepts `JSON` and sends `XML`. And then pass the first one to the `ServerThatUsesXML`. And pass the second one to the `ServerThatUsesJSON`. This solution looks better that the first one (at least it's more efficient).

My question is: can I make two `accept` functions for example `accpetXML` and `acceptJSON` and in the `accept` function, depending on the type of the caller, I either call the `XML` version or the `JSON` version. The code should look something like this:

```
public void accept(String input, ....)
{
    if (senderType == ServerThatUsesXML)
        acceptJSON(converter.convertToJSON(input));
    else
        acceptXML(converter.convertToXML(input));
}
```

Comment: "whenever the ServerThatUsesXML sends something to the adapter, the adapter converts it to JSON and forward it to the ServerThatUsesJSON.", does this mean you send to the adapter when you want to send to the JSON-server? If you know the target server accepts JSON, can you not just convert data to JSON and send directly?

Comment: I think the question from @Lini is asking whether you can modify the `Server` implementations to use the `Converter` directly and eliminate the `Adapter`.

Comment: The servers are just an example to clarify. My question is all about the adapter pattern. I'm not facing a problem with a certain server. Long story short, I'm asking about wether it's possible to act differently depending on the type of the caller of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GoF mentions "two-way adapters" on page 143.

> Specifically, they're useful when two different clients need to view an object differently.

With the `Server` interface, however, different clients view it in exactly the same way. There is only one interface to adapt rather than two, so this is a clue that a two-way adapter may not be suitable.

The example from the GoF shows a two-way class adapter using multiple inheritance.

> Multiple inheritance is a viable solution in this case because the interfaces of the adapted classes are substantially different. The two-way class adapter conforms to both of the adapted classes and can work in either system.

Clearly this tells us that a two-way class adapter is not suitable to the `Server` use case. I think it may be sufficient evidence to conclude that adapting two classes with the same interface is not a viable use for two-way adapters at all. While the GoF does not mention a two-way *object* adapter (using composition rather than multiple inheritance) it would seem to encounter the same problem of different input formats to one API.

Incidentally, the problem with different String formats is more an effect of [Stringly Typed](https://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) programming. It can be solved by programming with objects instead of primitives. If the servers would deserialize their inputs, the problem vanishes. This is a surprisingly common problem: servers have type information (because they know what format to accept) but they throw that information away by passing serialized data (such as a String) to another object that has to deal with different formats.

Returning to the topic of the Adapter pattern, you might implement different (one-way) adapters: one specifically for the XML server that converts to JSON and another specifically for the JSON server that converts to XML. This solution is similar to the comments of passing the `Converter` into each `Server` and making the String format the `Server`s' problem, which is essentially the same deserialization solution that avoids propagating Strings.